# Django Login/Logout Logger

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a `django` project where I need to know how much time each user spends on the site.

The first thing that came to my mind was that since I have a `CustomUser` I can create my own login/logout view and populate a table with login and logout and the user's identifier. However, I wanted to know if there is a callback function for `django.contrib.auth.urls`. So I can use the default login form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/). Django has several [built-in Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/) that trigger when various events occur. For example, `post_save` and `post_delete`. You can write handlers that listen for these signals to trigger whenever the session (or token, JWT, so on, depending on your authentication backend) is created or destroyed. You can then perform actions (like updating a database table) whenever these events occur.